# How to efficiently select unique lists from the list of lists?

Tags: python

I have a big list of lists with different sizes. How to efficiently create a new list containing only lists with unique combination of numbers?

```
input_list = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [3,4], [3,4,5]]
result = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [3,4]]
```

Elements in lists are ordered.

Comment: `set(map(tuple, input_list))`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` and take the key:

`groupby` objects yield key-group pairs where the group is a generator.

It can Group consecutive items together

```
import itertools
input_list = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [1,2], [3,4], [3,4,5]]
input_list.sort()
res_list = list(item for item,_ in itertools.groupby(input_list))


def print_groupby(iterable):
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable):
        print("key: '{}'--> group: {}".format(k, list(g)))
print_groupby(input_list)
print('result is:', res_list)
```

Outputs:

```
key: '[1, 2]'--> group: [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
key: '[3, 4]'--> group: [[3, 4]]
key: '[3, 4, 5]'--> group: [[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
result is: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```